# Create nested resources from check boxes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have 3 models which are connected like this:

```
class Appointment < ActiveRecord::Base  
    has_many :service_items
    has_many :services, through: :service_items

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :service_items
end

class ServiceItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :appointment
    belongs_to :service
end

class Service < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :service_items
end
```

For the new appointments form I want a list of checks for each available service. And the service items of the new appointment should be created from the selected boxes.

How do I build such a form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the method you are looking for is `collection_check_boxes`. Check it out in the [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_check_boxes).

Comment: I'm using rails 3.2. I think it's only available from 4.0. Any advice for 3.2?

Comment: Oh, you are right, I forgot that his is brand new stuff, sorry. In 3.2 you would probably iterate over your `Service` models and generate one checkbox for each and store the IDs of the checked models in a param. A quick search on Google returned this article which demonstrates what you are trying to achieve: http://millarian.com/programming/ruby-on-rails/quick-tip-has_many-through-checkboxes/